# Glide/Picasso не загружают изображения через url (JSON)

Tags: android, json, retrofit, picasso, glide

Я получаю данные с помощью retrofit и вставляю их в recyclerView в новой активити.
TextView заполняются без проблем, но imageView ничего не выводит, если добавить error в Glide - выводит изображение ошибки. С Picasso та же история. Не могу понять в чем дело, испробовал много способов

Вот мой Adapter

```
class SearchRecyclerViewAdapter internal constructor(context: Context?, data: Albums) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
 private val mData: Albums
 private val mInflater: LayoutInflater
private var mClickListener: ItemClickListener? = null
// inflates the row layout from xml when needed
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row_table, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

// binds the data to the TextView in each row
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val data = mData.results.get(position)
    holder.tvAlbumName.text=data.collectionName
    holder.tvArtistName.text=data.artistName
    holder.tvSongNumber.text=data.trackCount.toString()

   // Picasso.get().load(data.collectionViewUrl).into(imageView)
    Glide.with(holder.logoImageView.context)
        .load(data.collectionViewUrl)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(holder.logoImageView);
    Log.d("Glide","URL изображения "+ data.collectionViewUrl)


}

// total number of rows
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mData.resultCount
}

// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
inner class ViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),View.OnClickListener {
     var tvAlbumName: TextView
     var tvArtistName: TextView
   var tvSongNumber: TextView
     var logoImageView:ImageView
    init {
        tvAlbumName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlbumName)
        tvArtistName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvArtistName)
        tvSongNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongsNumber)
        logoImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.logoImageView)
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)

    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener!!.onItemClick(view, adapterPosition)
    }

}

// data is passed into the constructor
init {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    mData = data
}

fun setClickListener(itemClickListener: ItemClickListener?) {
    mClickListener = itemClickListener
}
interface ItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(view: View?, position: Int)
}
```

}
Вот код ошибки через listener
2021-12-22 18:04:02.989 13892-13892/com.myprojects.registrationapp E/Ошибка: Вот эта коварная ошибка com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There were 8 root causes:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail

Comment: Добавьте листнер, чтобы отловить ошибку и узнать детали `.listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                 //on load failed
                    return false;
                }
)`

Comment: Без логов ошибки можно только гадать. Моё первое предположение - ссылки на http протоколе и он не разрешён явно в манифесте.